# DIV to appear when hover over link inside parapgraph

Tags: html, css

This is what I have currently: http://jsfiddle.net/nw9n1658/

I want to make the secondary-box to appear only when I hover over link inside paragraph, can I do it while only using CSS (if so how?) or I have to get familiar with JS.

```
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
}

.primary-box {
  background-color: #ffff99;
  margin: auto;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  border: dotted 2px #b2b26b;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.secondary-box {
  display: none;
  background-color: #ffff99;
  margin: auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 120px;
  border: dotted 2px #b2b26b;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.primary-box p {
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.3;
  text-align: justify;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.main-text:hover ~ .secondary-box {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that `div` elements shouldn't be children of `p` elements.

```
<div class="primary-box">
  <h2>Heading</h2>
  <div class="main-text">
    Here is some text. The box only appears when hovering over <a href="#">this link</a>
    <div class="secondary-box">
      <p>This is text inside a box</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you modify your HTML and change the `p` element with class `.main-text` to a `div` element, then you could use the following selector:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/8rp40212/)

```
.main-text a:hover ~ .secondary-box {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

This works because the `a` element and `.secondary-box` elements are siblings.

If you want the box to stay visible when hovering over it, add in another selector:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/18ozb7t0/)

```
.main-text a:hover ~ .secondary-box,
.secondary-box:hover {
    display: inline-block;
}
```